# "this" reference inside of object function

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
function PatternField(id, name, pattern) {
    ...

    this.check = function () {
        var field = this.elem.val();
        ...
    };

    this.elem.keyup(this.check);
    this.elem.change(this.check);
}
```

When the execution comes to `check` function `var field = this.elem.val();` it turns out that `this` points to `elem` rather than actual object.
How can I access real `this` from inside this object function?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if `this` is referring to the element already why not use `this.value` inside the `check` method?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, good idea :) I just wanted to know how to solve this problem in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
this.check = function() {
    var field = this.elem.val();
    ...
}.bind(this);
```

The important part being `bind(this)` which controls the scope of the function once it is invoked/called (note that the function is not invoked immediately when using `bind`, you are manipulating the definition, if you will...); in this case, retaining the scope of PatternField. [Check the docs regarding `bind` at MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

---

In other words (in regards to some comment that magically deleted itself):

It makes sure that the scope of this.check (when called) will be whatever is passed to the first parameter of `bind`, overriding whatever might naturally occur. If the you want `this` to reference `PatternField` within the `this.check` method, the `bind` method of `Function` will enable this capability.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that OP was passing `this.check` as an event handler.

Comment: @BlueSkies np, i hope the extra explanation helps too. :)

Answer (score 4):

Like @zamnuts answered, you can use the ES5 `bind` method.

But if you want to do it *the old way*, i.e., supporting old browsers without a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility), you can use:

```
var that = this;
this.check = function () {
    var field = that.elem.val();
    ...
};
```

Comment: Yes, this closure method is the safest in terms of legacy support. If older compatibility is of concern, this is your best bet.

Comment: @zamnuts: Not only that but it also preserves the actual `this` as it is passed through the event. This way you can access `this` within the scope as well (assuming it is of use) as well as `that` to get access to your object.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl yea no doubt! however, in most cases a reference to the object is available within the callback arguments, and switching the value of `this` could be confusing, for example in a series of prototype definitions, where one would assume `this` would always be the primary subject.